# About @media in CSS

Tags: css

my question about **@media code in CSS**
when I create a website I use @media in media to change on many screens like this:

```
@media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    @media (min-width: 280px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 11px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 320px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 360px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 411px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 450px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 24px;
        }
    }
}
```

This method is correct or not?
Is there a method better than that?

Comment: This is a valid method

Answer (score 0):

For this @media query , this is the only way can be can be doing different screen size that set to specification settings by using css

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be valid. I can show You how I like to handle RWD with `@media`

1. Create a mixin like so

```css
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
   @if $point == desktop {
     @media (min-width: 70em) { @content ; }}
   @else if $point == laptop {
     @media (min-width: 64em) { @content ; }}
   @else if $point == tablet {
     @media (min-width: 50em) { @content ; }}
   @else if $point == phablet {
     @media (min-width: 37.5em)  { @content ; }}  
     @else if $point == mobileonly { 
       @media (max-width: 37.5em)  { @content ; }}
}
```

2. Use it like this

```css
.podcasts {
  margin: 1em auto;
  @include breakpoint(phablet){
  width: 100%;
  }
}
```

It's just a suggestion, Maybe You'll like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a valid method. Maybe you can also delete the duplicated check for **@media (min-width: 280px)**, like this:

```
@media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .main-header .main-textmonial {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 320px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 360px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 411px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 450px) {
        .main-header .main-textmonial {
            font-size: 24px;
        }
    }
}
```

But again the way you did it is valid for this **@media** query.